# On the rigorous definition of the sum or a function of two random variables

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, random-variables

*Edit: In some sense the questions have been solved. The issue is actually about independence. Please see comments.*

Suppose that we toss a coin and the outcome is either head or tail. So the sample space is $\Omega=\{H,T\}$ and the probability measure is given by $\mathbb{P}(H)=\mathbb{P}(T)=\frac{1}{2}$. Now define a random variable $X_1$ by $X_1(H)=0,  X_1(T)=1$ Now suppose that we toss the coin again and get a random variable $X_2$, which is defined in the same way as $X_1$. Then by common sense that the random variable $$X_1+X_2$$ can attain value 1 by firstly the head is up and then the tail is the up side.

However, the first method of defining the sum of two random variables would be $$(X_1+X_2)(\omega)=X_1(\omega)+X_2(\omega)$$ and by this method the sum would not attain value 1 and this contradicts the common sense in the example above.

The second method is to construct product of the sample space. Let $\Omega_2$ be defined in the same way as $\Omega$, and $\Omega_2$ represents that we toss the coin again. Let $\Omega_0$ be the Cartesian product of $\Omega$ and $\Omega_2$ so $\Omega_0=\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$. The probability measure on the $\Omega_0$ is defined by $\mathbb{P}(E_0)=\mathbb{P}(E)*\mathbb{P}(E_2)$ for any events ie. subsets of sample space. We can view the random variable $X_1$ to be defined on the $\Omega$ and the random variable $X_2$ to be defined on the $\Omega_2$. Then let $X_i$ to be extended to random variables on $\Omega_0$ by the natural projections to the first and second coordinates of Cartesian product, respectively. Now they are defined on the same space so we can add them up by the first method. For example, if we use this second method, $$(X_1+X_2) (TH) = X_1(T)+X_2(H)=1$$ and this agrees with the common sense in the example.

Questions:

1. Does the linearity property of expectation, namely $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$, holds for the first or second or both methods of adding two random variables?
2. I understand that this topic of the rigorous definition of the sum of two random variables is explained in [reference to the MSE answer by Brent Kerby](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458555/rigorous-definition-of-sum-of-two-random-variables), but is there a textbook reference? Or in general the definition of a function of two random variables.
3. Which definition do people usually mean when they say the sum of two random variables?

I'm a novice in probability theory. Thank you.

Comment: If you toss the coin twice then the probability space is bigger and the sample space is something like  $\Omega= \{H,T\}^2$

Comment: Your first construction has two coins that are perfectly dependent: the first coin yields heads if and only if the second coin also yields heads. The second example has two coins that are independent, which is the "common sense" interpretation of two coin flips. More generally, $X$ and $Y$ can have other types of dependence, depending on how they are defined; defining two random variables on a common probability space automatically induces some sort of dependence/independence structure. Regardless of dependence, $E[X+Y]=E[X] + E[Y]$ always holds.

Comment: @angryavian Ok I see. The random variable $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent since the events $X_1=0$ and $X_2=0$ are exactly the same subset of $\Omega$, and so if one try to calculate the conditional probabilities they'll be 1. This makes sense a lot. So the conclusion is my model for tossing the coins is wrong and should be $\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$ from the beginning.